# end curl command?

Tags: command-line, curl

```
curl "https://dummy.net/v1/users/titles/privacy'
> -XGET \
> -H ‘Referer:https://dummy.net/friday/?f’ \
> -H ‘Authorization:Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ \
> -H ‘User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 7.00) ’ \
> -H ‘Accept-Language:en-US’
```

here how can I close the command and run it?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close the double quoted string that you opened on the first line of your command (you used a single quote at the end of the URL, probably by mistake). Just press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and start over.  Then make sure that you close each quote properly.

The `>` prompt is the *secondary prompt* (`$PS2`). It is displayed in situation where more input is needed to complete the current command.  In your case, you have an open double quote, so it's waiting for you to close it.

Here's another situation where that prompt crops up:

```
$ for str in hello world
> do
> echo "$str"
> done
hello
world
```

The command is not done until I type `done` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so instead of trying to run the half entered command `for str in hello world`, the shell expects me to finish the loop by typing `done`.

Or, close to the thing you actually did:

```
$ echo "hello
> this is line 2
> Quotes like 'these' don't matter
> because we have an un-closed double quote at the start
> Now, we'll close it"
hello
this is line 2
Quotes like 'these' don't matter
because we have an un-closed double quote at the start
Now, we'll close it
```

Comment: Also, the quotes on the continuation lines are fancy (or "smart") unicode quotes, which the shell will not recognize. For shell commands, you must stick to plain ASCII quotes.